# Xcode: Application Windows are Expected to have a Root View Controller at the end of Application Launch

Tags: javascript, html, xcode

I am new to Xcode and have tried to run a simple app (i can give code if needed) with the emualtor, and an although it says 'Build Successful', a Target Output says "Application Windows are Expected to have a Root View Controller at the end of Application Launch"

Is there a fix you could tell me please? Again this is the first time I've used Xcode so sorry if it's a simple mistake :)

Thanks a lot x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Application Delegate class in the `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` method you need to set a root view controller to your window like this :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The message should disappear after that.

Comment: there's an error beside the code i entered - says 'Use of unidentified identifier'

Comment: I've added a more detailed code. You need to do that in the implementation file (.m)

Comment: thanks. it keeps asking when i say `viewController` if i mean `UIViewController` though.

Comment: Please take a look at the official documentation :  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController